# Is There Any Default Session Library in NextJS? Or what can we use instead of sessions?

Tags: session, cookies, next.js

What library can I use for NextJS? Is there any offical/default library except "next-session" or "iron-session"? Or what alternatives can we use instead of sessions in NextJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [official NextJS docout](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication) for a list of auth providers in NextJS. It has a few great options listed like:

1. Auth0
2. Passport
3. Supabase
4. Supertokens
   ... and many more (probably should check out the list for selecting one that matches your requirements)

For temporary data storage try using one of these:

1. Redis
2. Amazon Elasticache
3. Memcached
4. BoltDB

Comment: But I want to use sessions for other purposes besides authentication. Like storing temporary data neccesary to handle app full functionalities.

Comment: Then I would suggest using caching DBs like [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis). It can be really helpful for storing temporary key-value pairs on server side. One client-side, you can directly use windows.localStorage

Comment: Can you refer a link for using redis for it? I never thinked about redis's caching system can be used on web apps. I don't have any idea how to use it.

Comment: First download the [Redis](https://redis.io/download) db. Then install the JS library whose link I have already shared on my previous comment. For JS there are many libraries but I personally prefer the official one. It is as simple as doing client.set() or client.get() and the data will always persist till your application is running(would be lost once you close your application).

Comment: But there will be plenty of users how can I make special keys for all each user? Which information is unique when user enters web page? I know how to use redis at backend development (in Rust, C#, Go lang). We set key,value with client.set() as you said. But how we define unique keys and how can we understand what time we must delete the keys? Because user can close the tab and leave.

Comment: The unique keys can be the any data unique for all users (for eg. the primary key in case of Relational DBs, _id in case of Non-relational DBs or just the username which usually is unique for most applications).

Comment: As per the time, that also depends on the application you are building. If security is the key aspect, delete the key frequently, like every day. If ease of access if the key aspect, keep the data for a longer duration. Alternatively, whenever a tab is closed you can trigger a event that deletes the cache for that user. At the end it completely depends on the type of application you are developing

Comment: OK, that reply is usefull. But there is one more question left because I'm confused a little bit. How can I match key on redis server to client's web browser or current tab session? With IP Address or something?

Comment: Please keep in mind that storing user information is not recommended at scale as it can hog up the memory providing less memory for the main application functions. I would suggest using JWT and storing it on user end for this purpose. This would limit memory usage on your end and distribute the storage requirement on each user's browser.

Comment: You can use JWT for this purpose. You can go through and understand how JWT works and how to implement it for better clarification. There will be lots of guide for implementing JWT in NextJS through a simple google search

Comment: I'm not going to store large amounts of user data, but if I can use Redis before JWT and secure it with a mapping method, I'd prefer to do it that way. The data I will store is small stuff but necessary for the application to work.